# How do I load a video into a HTML5 page with javascript using onclick

Tags: javascript, html, video, load

I want to call a function onclick (which I know works) then load it into the page:

I'm trying to create a video element in HTML5 including some attributes for it.

I know it works because I tested it with the following alert:

`alert("createSmallVideo has been called");`

I've commented the alert now and I know the function is being called but why isn't the video being displayed on the web page:

```
function createSmallVideo(){
    //alert("createSmallVideo has been called");

    var video = document.createElement("video");

    video.setAttribute("id", "VideoElement");
    video.setAttribute("src", "videos/small.ogv");
    video.setAttribute("controls", "controls");
    video.setAttribute("preload", "auto");
    document.getElementById("#VideoContainer").appendChild(video);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help!

Comment: What browser are you using and are you using some kind of developement tools (firebug for example)? If you do, is the console showing you anything? Is the given video-source correct?

Comment: `#VideoContainer` should be changed to `VideoContainer`. The `#` is something done for CSS selectors (jQuery also uses that syntax).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there is no element on your page with an id of `#VideoContainer` (or if there is there shouldn't be).  An element Id cannot contain a `#`.  If you open your JavaScript console you'll probably find a null reference error message.  Try removing the `#` from your call to `document.getElementById()`.

Comment: I'm definetely using too much jQuery for element selection, totally overlooked this. +1

Comment: That's working, thanks for that but now I I just want it to play straight away. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: After `appendChild` call `video.play()`.

Answer (score 1):

you can preload it with javascript too

```
function loadVideo(videoUrl){
var video;
try {
    video = new Video();
} catch(e) {
    video = document.createElement('video');
}
video.src = videoUrl;
bindOnce(video, 'canplaythrough', function() {alert("Loaded");});
video.onerror = function(e){alert("Error");};
video.load();
}
```